# How to make a submit button send the input values only if the input values matches with the mysql data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a simple registration page that makes the user  enter the username and email.
The problem is how can I check if the input values(email)already exists in the mysql when I press the submit button without going to the next page instantly ? if the input value doesn't exist in the mysql database I want to display a message like "email not registered". I'm trying to use ajax,jquery, and php but I cant find a decent solution.

```
//this is the script to check if the emails that the users entered matches.
//I'm trying to post the values to the'checkPage.php' to check if the email exists
//The problem is how can I on move to the next page after the result have been returned?
Sorry for my bad explanation.

<script>
  $('input#submitbutton').on('click',function(){
    var mail=$('input#mail').val();
    var mail2=$('input#mail2').val();

    if($.trim(mail)===$.trim(mail2)){
      $.post('checkPage.php',{mail:mail},function(data){
        $('#name-data').text(data);  // displays the result if the email exists or not
      }); 
    }else{

    }           
  });enter code here
</script>

//CheckPage.php
//I want the registration page to go to the next page only if the email
//haven't been found in the mysql database.

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['mail'])&&isset($_POST['mail2'])){
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $mail2 = $_POST['mail2'];
    try{
      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); echo "connected";
      $db = mysql_select_db("db",$con);
      $query = mysql_query("select email,id from user where email ='".    mysql_real_escape_string(trim($mail))."'",$con);  
      echo (mysql_num_rows($query)!==0) ? mysql_result($query,0,'email'):'none';
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
    }
  }
?>
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this;

```
$('input#submitbutton').on('click',function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var mail=$('input#mail').val();
      var mail2=$('input#mail2').val();

       if($.trim(mail)===$.trim(mail2)){
          $.post('checkPage.php',{mail:mail},function(data){
              $('#name-data').text(data);  // displays the result if the email exists or not
              if (data !== "none") {
                $('#your_form_id').submit();    
              }
          }); 
       }else{

       }           
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put your javascript code in `$(document).ready();`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code here
    $('input#submitbutton').on('click',function(){

        var mail=$('input#mail').val();
        var mail2=$('input#mail2').val();

        if($.trim(mail)===$.trim(mail2)){
            $.post('checkPage.php',{mail:mail},function(data){
                $('#name-data').text(data);  // displays the result if the email exists or not
            }); 
        }else{

        }           
    });e
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all on submit button make an ajax call as follows

```
<script>
function myformsubmit()
{
var mail=$('#mail').val();
$.post( "check.php", { mail:  mail})
.done(function( data ) {
  if(msg == 'error')
 {
  $('#diverr').html('Match found');
  return false;
 }
 else
 {
 //redirect to a valid page
 }
 });
}
```

In the check.php you will have to get your data by post make an sql select query loop thru the mail ids returned by the query and if there is a match found return 'error' or return blank